# SendEmail with Indy components

Tags: windows, delphi, email, compiler-construction, indy

I try to send an email, but I have a problem, however, I found this code on the web:

```
Uses
Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
Dialogs, StdCtrls, IdMessage, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient,
IdMessageClient, IdSMTP, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdIOHandler,
IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase, IdSMTPBase

procedure SendSimpleMail;
var
Msg: TIdMessage;
DestAddr: TIdEmailAddressItem;
begin
Msg := TIdMessage.Create(Self); //error here
Msg.From.Text := 'name';
Msg.From.Address := 'username@gmail.com';
Msg.Subject := 'Test';

DestAddr := Msg.Recipients.Add;
DestAddr.Text := 'name';
DestAddr.Address := 'username@yahoo.com';
Msg.Body.Add('simple test mail.');

tIdSMTP.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
tIdSMTP.Port := 25;
tIdSMTP.AuthenticationType := atLogin; //error here (2 error)
tIdSMTP.Username := 'username@gmail.com';
tIdSMTP.Password := 'password';
tIdSMTP.Connect;
tIdSMTP.Authenticate;
tIdSMTP.Send(Msg);
tIdSMTP.Disconnect;
end;
```

But however, I noted many mistakes and I am missing a component of Indy.
Compiler errors:

```
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(36): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Self'
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(46): E2233 Property 'Host' inaccessible here
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(47): E2233 Property 'Port' inaccessible here
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(48): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'AuthenticationType'
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(48): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'atLogin'
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(49): E2233 Property 'Username' inaccessible here
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(50): E2233 Property 'Password' inaccessible here
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(51): E2076 This form of method call only allowed for class methods
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(52): E2076 This form of method call only allowed for class methods
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(53): E2076 This form of method call only allowed for class methods
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(54): E2076 This form of method call only allowed for class methods
[DCC Error] Project1.dpr(5): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'Unit1.pas'
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: One thing is adding `IdEMailAddress` to your uses clause to make the compiler know the `TIdEmailAddressItem`, but another is that the example is basically wrong and it's for Indy 9 (because of `atLogin` authentication type), what version of Indy are you using ? You can check that if you hold the `CTRL` key and click e.g. `IdSMTP` from your uses clause and then check where the `IdSMTP.pas` is stored. If it's in `Indy9` or `Indy10` folder.

Comment: ok thanks, now the errors are decreased, but now are 3 errors (I edited the first post), i have Indy9 and Indy10, but when i click on idSMTP i get an error: Unable to locate file idSMTP.pas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code from your question is written for Indy 9 and from your compiler error seems you're using Indy 10. To your compiler errors:

- `Undeclared identifier: Self` - the `Self` is the pointer to the class instance itself and since you didn't write the `SendSimpleMail` as a class method but just as a standalone procedure, you don't have any `Self` just because you don't have any class. The class method you could write for instance for your form class like e.g. `TForm1.SendSimpleMail`, where inside of that method the `Self` would have meaning of the `TForm1` instance, the form itself.
- And the rest of the errors you got because you were accessing the `TIdSMTP` class, not the object instance. Commonly used practice is to declare a local variable, create an object instance assigning it to that variable, work with that object (variable) and free the object instance.

I would try something like this (tested with Indy 10 shipped with Delphi 2009):

```
uses
  IdSMTP, IdMessage, IdEMailAddress;

procedure SendSimpleMail;
var
  IdSMTP: TIdSMTP;
  IdMessage: TIdMessage;
  IdEmailAddressItem: TIdEmailAddressItem;
begin
  IdSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
  try
    IdSMTP.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
    IdSMTP.Port := 25;
    IdSMTP.AuthType := satDefault;
    IdSMTP.Username := 'username@gmail.com';
    IdSMTP.Password := 'password';
    IdSMTP.Connect;
    if IdSMTP.Authenticate then
    begin
      IdMessage := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
      try
        IdMessage.From.Name := 'User Name';
        IdMessage.From.Address := 'username@gmail.com';
        IdMessage.Subject := 'E-mail subject';
        IdMessage.Body.Add('E-mail body.');

        IdEmailAddressItem := IdMessage.Recipients.Add;
        IdEmailAddressItem.Address := 'recipient@email.com';

        IdSMTP.Send(IdMessage);
      finally
        IdMessage.Free;
      end;
    end;
    IdSMTP.Disconnect;
  finally
    IdSMTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, but now i have a last error: [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(42): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'satDefault'

Comment: I was not sure with that, since in the [`reference`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdSMTP_AuthType.html) there's the `atDefault`, but in the version shipped with Delphi 2009 it is the `satDefault`. So try to use `atDefault` instead.

Comment: Yes `satDefault` was originally named `atDefault` in earlier Indy 10 releases and was later renamed.

Comment: I just want to add a note. you must add IdEMailAddress to use TIdEmailAddressItem

Answer (score 0):

For google smtp you need to use TLS or SSL!
http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

Your procedure sample is write for INDY9 and if you use INDY10 can't compile.
You need to make adjustements.

Comment: No, the code is basically wrong. You need to create an instance of `tIdSMTP`, not work with the class itself.