# SendMail with TIdSMTP Connection Time Out

Tags: delphi, smtp, sendmail, indy

I am not able to send emails using `TIdSMTP` I am getting the following message: `Socket Error # 10060 / Connection timed out.`

I am using version Delphi XE6

[image]

Here is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  IdSMTP : TIdSMTP;
  IdMessage : TIdMessage;
begin
  IdSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create (Nil);
  IdMessage := TIdMessage.Create (Nil);
  IdSMTP.Host := 'mail.mysmtp.com';
  IdSMTP.Port := 25;
  IdSMTP.Connect ();
  IdMessage.From.Address := 'test@mysmtp.com';
  IdMessage.From.Name := 'Contato';
  IdMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'test@hotmail.com';
  IdMessage.Subject := 'Contato test';
  IdMessage.Body.Text := 'test';
  IdSMTP.Send (IdMessage);
  IdSMTP.Disconnect ();
  FreeAndNil (IdMessage);
  FreeAndNil (IdSMTP);
end;
```

Comment: Is the exception raised at IdSMTP.connect ?  Can you connect via Telnet to your SMTP server?

Comment: are you sure about the host? Maybe unrelated but some authentication would be missing too (Username/Password/ Pop before SMTP), Port, TSL ... Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11157460/1699210), maybe you will have to refine your question.

Comment: Note that you can simply write `TIdSMTP.Create` and `TIdMessage.Create` without (nil). Also use a try .. finally and put theFree / FreeAndNil in the finally block to remove the risk of memory leaks.

Comment: I didn't know there was a such thing as an SMTP server that doesn't require any kind of authentication...

Comment: @mjn In this particular case, it absolutely is leaking both `IdSMTP` and `IdMessage` objects.

Comment: @JerryDodge I don't think connect requires authentication.

Comment: @JohnEasley Yes I see that, my point was why? I believe any such server *should* require authentication. It's a huge security risk not to.

Comment: @JerryDodge not if server access is restricted to the local LAN.

Comment: @JohnEasley And if malware manages to get installed on the local LAN? I say that because precisely that happened on our own work network.

Comment: @JerryDodge if users are within the same domain, authentication may not be required - bob@mydomain sends to cindy@mydomain. I'm just saying that a call to Connect does not always require authentication, even if authentication is required to send mail.

Answer (score 1):

From Google: A socket error in the 10060 range is a Winsock error. It is generally caused by either outgoing connection problems or connection problems on the host end.

I don't know if you sanitized this code to post it or not, but I'd say the culprit is either the hostname or the username on the from address.

Winsock will attempt to create a connection to the hostname. If it fails to get the expected ACK, it'll generate a timeout error. I've also seen this happen when the domain name isn't resolved by DNS.

Also, what was mentioned earlier regarding authentication ... the lack of response from the SMTP host could be due to improper authentication. It all depends on how the host's SMTP service was configured, so it could just ignore unauthorized requests.

You need to see if you must pass in a username/pwd with the SMTP request, or read the mailbox first (read before write, so to speak). I cannot imagine anybody configuring an SMTP server without requiring some kind of authentication, because otherwise you've got what amounts to an "open relay" where any process can send out unlimited traffic through it.

Also, the from address might be required to be valid. That is, 'test@mysmtp.com' would require a user/mailbox for 'test' to exist, as opposed to '*@mysmtp.com' that would work with ANY user/mailbox name.

All of these could result in a timeout because the SMTP host could be configured to simply ignore improper and unauthenticated requests.